# Symfonty 6.1 to 6.2 upgrade: Invalid service id in FileLoader

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have recently been trying to upgrade from Symfony 6.1 to 6.2. In doing so though..something appears to have broken. Does anyone have any clue what changed from 6.1 to 6.2? I have tried looking and continue to do so..but I haven't been able to find any meaningful change that breaks it. The setup docs all show the same formatting for all the available files.

I am on PHP 8.1.11

When I update my composer.json to bring everything up to 6.2, the console throws the following error:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In FileLoader.php line 178:
!!
!!    Invalid service id: "MyNamespace\" in /var/www/html/config/services.yaml (whic
!!    h is being imported from "/var/www/html/src/Kernel.php").
!!
!!
!!  In ContainerBuilder.php line 911:
!!
!!    Invalid service id: "MyNamespace\".
!!
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

Nothing has changed, and if I change it all back to 6.1 and reupdate composer..it works just fine.

Below is my services.yaml

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    MyNamespace\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../vendor/'
            - '../var/'
    _instanceof:
        MyNamespace\Enum\AbstractEnumType:
            tags: ['app.doctrine_enum_type']

                  # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

I have downgraded back to 6.1, that works.

I have tried renaming or removing parts of my class..that doesn't work.

Update: Here is a copy of my kernel file:

```
 namespace MyNamespace;

 use MyNamespace\Enum\AbstractEnumType;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
 use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

 class Kernel extends BaseKernel
  {
 use MicroKernelTrait;

 public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
 {
     $typesDefinition = [];
     if ($container->hasParameter('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory.types')) {
         $typesDefinition = $container->getParameter('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory.types');
     }
     $taggedEnums = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.doctrine_enum_type');

     foreach ($taggedEnums as $enumType => $definition) {
         /** @var $enumType AbstractEnumType */
         $typesDefinition[$enumType::NAME] = ['class' => $enumType];
     }
     $container->setParameter('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory.types', $typesDefinition);
 }
 }
```

Update 2: I have attached the code for my abstract enum & composer.json

composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.252",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.13",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^3.4",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^4.2",
        "monolog/monolog": "^3.2",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.2",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.9",
        "ramsey/uuid": "^4.5",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^9.7.0",
        "symfony/amazon-mailer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.47",
        "symfony/mime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.8",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true,
            "phpstan/extension-installer": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyNamespace\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyNamespace\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.1.*"
        },
        "public-dir": "/"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpstan/extension-installer": "^1.1",
        "phpstan/phpstan-symfony": "^1.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.2",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.1.*"
    }
}
```

AbstractEnumType.php

```
namespace MyNamespace\Enum;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType;

abstract class AbstractEnumType extends StringType
{
    abstract public static function getEnumClass(): string;

    public function getName(): string
    {
        throw new \Exception('getName should be overwritten by child class');
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): ?\BackedEnum
    {
        if($value instanceof \BackedEnum){
            return $value;
        }

        $value = parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);

        if($value === null){
            return null;
        }

        //  https://www.php.net/manual/en/backedenum.tryfrom.php
        return $this::getEnumClass()::tryFrom($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): ?string
    {
        return $value?->value;

    }

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        return 'TEXT';
    }


}
```

Comment: So do you still have `App\Kernel` or is it `MyNamespace\Kernel`?

Comment: The kernels is inside namespace MyNamespace;

I will add my kernel to the main post.

Comment: 6.2 was just released and given that App is the standard namespace it's possible that a bug crept in.  I'd suggest creating a new 6.2 app from stratch, add one service and change the root namespace to see if the problem still occurs.  And then maybe open a [Symfony discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions).

Comment: Could you please share your composer.json ?

Comment: Just to satisfy my own curiosity I installed a new 6.2 app, tweaked half a dozen files or so and successful changed App to MyNamespace.  It all worked as expected.  I suppose the problem could be with your enum stuff.  Perhaps you could update your question with the code for AbstractEnumType as well as one child.

Comment: @Skuti I have added my composer.json to the original post

Comment: @Cerad I have added my AbstractEnumType file to the original post as well :) Thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: What happend if you remove the exclude part of your services.yaml?